# Cursor and Pivot point not centre of Object

Tags: modeling

I have 2 objects in my scene. I'm selecting the shape which looks like a 3 pointed star and trying cursor to selected and cursor to active. But the cursor isn't right in the middle of the object from the middle section its halved non symmetric as seen in the measurements. But on the rectangle when I do cursor to selected or cursor to active the cursor is right in the centre. How can I get the cursor spot on in the centre of the 3 pointed object?

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object center is based on the whole area.
To find the *vertical center*, select only the highest and lowest vertices and snap cursor to them.

*Origin is at the object's center, 3D cursor is at the 'vertical' center*

[image]

Comment: Thanks heaps for that Jay!!!

Kind regards.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :).